# Elasticsearch Doc[‘field_name’] returns unexpected big number

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, scripting

I'm using elasticsearch 1.7. I'm running following query and get very weird result. I couldn't find anything warnings or errors on elasticsearch logs.

Here is the query:

```
POST /myIndex/en/_search
{
  "size": 1,
  "script_fields": {
    "toTestField": {
      "script": "doc['popularity'].value"
    }
  }
```

Here is the result:

```
    {
  "took": 87,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 2,
    "successful": 2,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3059534,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "myIndex",
        "_type": "en",
        "_id": "12345",
        "_score": 1,
        "fields": {
          "toTestField": [
            4607464916994563600
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I try this query on a different machine with same data and settings. But one of them gives the normal result, the other one give this weird result.

Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the doc

```
    {
  "_index": "myIndex",
  "_type": "en",
  "_id": "12345",
  "_version": 1455227455,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "popularity": 15.0,
    "name": "Allzek",
    "id": "41191634",
    "language": "en",
    "lastRankedDate": 1472620503000
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you define "weird result" in more details? maybe also provide the sample document with id 12345

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that.
12345 is document id.
And result should 15 but it returns 4607464916994563600

Comment: Can you show that document please?

Comment: Apparently, this was a elasticsearch 1.7 bug. It is fixed 2.0 ([issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/20282))